# Running sh.exe in windows cmd.exe: command not found

Tags: windows, cygwin, cmd.exe, sh

For some reason I need to run a (hopefully simple) `sh` file under Windows and be able to do so from another application. I can do that using cygwin, but for various reasons I need this operation to be easy to reproduce on another machine (installing cygwin on another machine is out of question).

The first logical step was to copy `sh.exe` to another location and try running it in Windows `cmd`. I got a few "missing library" errors, but after copying:

- cyggcc_s-1.dll
- cygreadline7.dll
- cygncursesw-10.dll
- cygiconv-2.dll
- cygintl-8.dll
- cygwin1.dll

I can run `sh.exe` in `cmd`.

I tried running the `sh` file with this copy of `sh.exe`, but now I get an error that `gawk` is missing. I tried to copy `gawk.exe` (and necessary libraries) to the same folder, but `sh.exe` can't see it (I also tried copying `gawk-4.1.1.exe`, but the result was the same).

I suspect `sh.exe` looks for some environment variable which would then point to the location of dependencies (such as `gawk.exe`), but I'm not sure what environment variable it is and if `sh.exe` respect plain windows environment variables.

So my question is, can I run `sh.exe` under Windows `cmd` (and eventually directly in windows) and if yes, then how do I go around the problem described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question a few ideas popped into my head and one of them was "If there is an environment variable that is missing, surely cygwin is setting it when I start it.".

I did a text search for `cygwin\bin` and `cygwin/bin` in the `cygwin` folder and the second one pointed me to `.bashrc` file. Turns out the path required by `sh.exe` was stored in plain old `PATH` environment variable.

In short, if I execute:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;.
```

in the `cmd`, I can then run `sh.exe` with the dependables placed in the same folder (it's likely I might need to replace `.` with some specific path later on, but it's good enough for now). Later on I'll probably have to move this to a batch file.